# What prevents the use of electric engines to assist with spacecraft launches? (Space Shuttle Booster Supplement)

Tags: electrical-engineering, aerospace-engineering, turbines, experimental-physics

Much power is used to get rocket off the platform on the initial launch? Could electric engines used like booster rockets work similar in the way they launch planes of an aircraft carrier? The electric turbines would disconnect at the top of the launch platform that could also be made taller. Could it save fuel by creating lift for the first 1000 ft or so?

[image] supplement

Comment: By "electric turbine engine" do you mean an [electric motor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_motor)? Also, after reading your other question on Physics SE, it is still not clear what you mean by "will it work?". How fast does it need to go? How much force does it need to generate? These are all things you need to figure out. Please add more details or ask more questions on the site if you need more information on engineering topics

Comment: @BarbalatsDilemma An engine that moves air using a turbine and electricity instead of jet fuel. Will it work as a whole?

Comment: just as a matter of terminology if you had an electric powered device that pushed air it would not be called a turbine. it would be called a fan, propellor, compressor, or perhaps pump. a turbine by definition extracts power from the fluid.

Comment: Muze, I tried to edit your question so that it is a bit more clear what you are looking for. I hope I have properly captured your intent.

Comment: reviewing the energy density of whatever fuel you like with whatever battery technology you like should put this question to rest. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_density.   Even knocking fuel values in half to account for carrying oxidizer for a rocket application the numbers are not even close.

Comment: What makes you think the  stealth bomber uses electric propulsion?  If doesn't.

Comment: @EricShain Thank for pointing that out. I am trying to clean up the irrelevant material across the board as I learn more.

Comment: I'm sorry to break this to you, but your idea isn't going to fly.

Comment: @EricShain can I ask you for help?

Comment: @Muze - there's nothing more to be done with this particular question.  There's already an answer in place, and your edits risk invalidating the answer.  And adding a work-in-progress non-answer doesn't help the post.  Please leave this post alone.  This is not the site to work out your fantastical ideations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Electric turbine engines

First off, "electric turbine engines" don't really exist. What you're probably thinking of is an electric version of the [jet turbine engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_engine#Turbine_powered), which is a type of combustion engine (it burns fuel). Air is sucked in the front, compressed by a compressor, then mixed with fuel and burned in a combustion section. A turbine extracts some of the energy from the air and uses it to power the compressor, while the rest of the air shoots out the back of the engine to provide thrust. The important thing to understand is that the turbine is extracting energy from the air, not generating thrust. The burning fuel adds energy to the air which is converted into thrust by the structure of the jet engine. The turbine is just a way of making the jet engine more compact, so it doesn't need a separate power source for the compressor.

The closest electric engine equivalent that I could find would be something like the [Airbus E-Fan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbus_E-Fan) (see also the [Airbus website](http://www.airbusgroup.com/int/en/corporate-social-responsibility/airbus-e-fan-the-future-of-electric-aircraft/technology-tutorial/E-Thrust.html)). It uses an electric motor to spin a fan, providing thrust. It does not use a turbine, it's more like a fancy propeller.

Apparently [Airbus is hoping to use the E-Fan on commercial passenger jets in the future](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/impossible-electric-airplane-takes-flight/), albeit using a gas-powered generator to provide electricity, so it might be able to provide enough thrust to launch a small rocket.

## Will this work for your application? (Edit: Space Shuttle booster replacement)

There are two problems with replacing the solid fuel booster rockets of the space shuttle with electric fans:

1. The booster rockets generate [13,800 kN of thrust *each* at liftoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_Solid_Rocket_Booster), for a total of 27,600 kN. By comparison, the E-Fan only produces 750 N, therefore you would need 37,000 electric engines to get the same thrust.
2. The booster rockets burn for 2 minutes and are ejected when the shuttle reaches an [altitude of 46 km](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle#Solid_rocket_boosters). At that height the atmosphere is [so thin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmosphere_of_Earth#/media/File:Comparison_US_standard_atmosphere_1962.svg) that an E-Fan wouldn't be able to produce any thrust. In fact, since the E-Fan works by "pushing" air through its duct, its performance would decrease as the atmosphere thinned, whereas the solid boosters do not need air to operate.

## Conclusion

You can't replace the space shuttle solid rocket boosters with electric fans/engines, even if you could solve the battery/fuel problem. The electric fans simply do not produce enough thrust. Even if they did they still require an atmosphere to work properly, but the space shuttle needs its boosters to take it most of the way out of the atmosphere. Neat idea, but I'm afraid it just won't work.

Comment: I'm hoping this can eliminate the need for booster rockets on the space shuttle.

Comment: @Jen Ok, cool idea. I will update my answer, could you please add that information to your question?

Comment: parking the shuttles in musems has completely eliminated the need for boosters

Comment: @Jen I'm not sure what you mean by your stealth bomber comment. 50,000 ft $\approx$ 15 km, i.e. a third of the height that the booster rockets reach. As for making the rail longer, consider that the maximum height a high-altitude balloon can reach is somewhere around 37 km, at which point it wouldn't have any buoyancy left to support a rail. At this point, I would suggest you look into [space elevators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_elevator), since they accomplish more or less what you want and may be more feasible than a balloon-held launch rail

Comment: I just used the stealth bomber as a general reference point for modern technology and doesn't fit this question.

Comment: The shuttle's solid rockets product produce 27,600 kN of thrust. You are off by a factor of 1000. You are also ignoring the three liquid fueled main engines.

Comment: @Eric quite right, I missed that kN, I will edit my answer later. It doesn't change my conclusions though

Comment: Its the difference between unlikely and impossible.

Comment: In addition to the factor of 1000, you need to mention the added mass of 37,000 fans and associated batteries. With rockets the mass is reduced as you use up fuel. With batteries, the mass is constant which is a problem for spacecraft.